# Double Nested Select

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im tring to get this query to work

```
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
FROM Student
WHERE courseNo IN
(SELECT courseNo
FROM Student
WHERE courseNo = 1001 IN
(SELECT dob
FROM Student
WHERE dob < `1985-09-12`));
```

But for some reason, it is saying empty set?

All the data is in the same table of Student. If it helps, dob is formatted YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Does the innermost select return anything (if executed standalone)? BTW, 1985 - 09 - 12 = 1964... Try `'1985-09-12'` instead.

Comment: No. Nothing at all. say there is an error near ' ' at line 1.

Comment: Have you heard about JOINs?

Comment: Syntax error in the outermost sub-query. What's  `... WHERE courseNo = 1001 IN ...` supposed to do?

Comment: It makes no difference with spaces or not. I have a similar query using dates that work perfectly. this is it: `SELECT studentid, 
CONCAT(fName,' ',lName) AS Student_Name, dob 
FROM Student 
WHERE dob IN 
(SELECT dob 
FROM Student 
WHERE dob < '1985-05-04');`

Comment: it finds only the students with `courseNo = 1001`

Comment: @Strawberry The idea is to only use `SELECT` I know about joins.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. But not one I'm prepared to pursue ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry Ok...

Comment: @jarlh With your first suggestion. it gives a result, but is an empty set.

Comment: Omg, so many comments about nothing, and nobody saw OP is missing `AND` after `1001`...

Comment: @Legionar, check 4th comment...

Comment: While I see you got the query to work, I am not convinced based on your comments that you got the result set you wanted.  Meaning is important, much more important that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an attribute missing between WHERE courseNo = 1001, and IN.
I am not sure about exactly you need, but maybe could be like this?:

```
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
FROM Student
WHERE courseNo IN
(SELECT courseNo
FROM Student
WHERE courseNo = 1001 AND dob IN
(SELECT dob
FROM Student
WHERE dob < '1985-09-12'));
```

And if so, make the query simpler it is suited for you? Try something like this:

```
SELECT studentid, fName, lName, dob
FROM Student
WHERE courseNo = 1001 and dob < '1985-09-12';
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
SELECT studentid,fName,lName,dob From Student
where courseNo ='1001' and dob<'1985-09-12'
```

Comment: No, Because I am trying to compare ages from another `courseNo` of `1000`

Comment: In this case, have you tried using or in place of second and

Comment: It needs to be able to do both of those. Not either of them.

Comment: In that case, the query with and will do the job.Did you try it ?

Comment: Thanks  for the gesture